# Network Point Tester

Tags: networking

Would someone be able to recommend a reliable tool that I could use in order to test if a network point is live please?

I need something that's very easy to use. Preferable something hand-held, that I can plug into a network point in my office and e.g. will light up green if the point is active, and red it not.

I know I can achieve the same thing by plugging in any network device with a network connection (e.g a laptop), but I don't have access to other devices all the time.

As far as I know the cabling is all Cat 5 or 7 and standard rj45 connection type.

Most of the tools I see are quite advanced and come with various addons and pieces that I will never use.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest solution would be to use something like this:
[image]

Simply plug the USB connector into a 5V portable power source, or a wall adapter. The LED lights should detect if there's activity on the network. These sell for less than 10$ at most suppliers.

Comment: What sort of 5V power source? That means I need two devices at all times, the tester and the power source? Ideally I wanted something pocket sized and portable.

Comment: Juste stick it to a 5V battery back for cell phones?  Tge kind you get at tge dollar store. https://images.app.goo.gl/ehpfZEJ4wjYkYFnN7

Comment: @TheOrdinaryGeek  You're welcome! I have to say I can't guarantee it will work because it depends on if the USB adapter powers on completely with just 5V instead of a USB connection. Don't see why it wouldn't though. It's a 10$ bet I would be willing to take rather than buying them complicated testers though.